# Bloquear chamadas AJAX indesejadas

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss, ddos

Fiz um teste no Google Plus, liguei o Firebug e inseri um post.
Ao analisar o Firebug recuperei a URL em que foi executada via AJAX.
Copiei a URL e executei no browser com a sessão activa.

Acontece que retornou um erro:

> O Firefox não consegue encontrar o ficheiro em https://plus.google.com...

Como bloquear uma requisição AJAX de modo que somente o sistema consiga executa-la?
Encontrei essa solução que identifica se a requisição é via AJAX ou não, mas não sei se é suficiente, se de algum modo é possível burlar o sistema:

```
function isHttpRequest() {
    if( @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tem no lado do servidor?

Comment: no caso seria só recusar requisições externas... da pra fazer isso com o firewall do servidor, ou não?

Comment: @Sergio php e nodejs.

Comment: @Filipe servidor apache ou nginx?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth tenho o apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nenhum sistema é infalível. Ponto! O que você pode fazer é adicionar camadas sequenciais de proteção.

- **Verificar  como a requisição foi feita**

Você mesmo já pesquisou e encontrou como fazer, mas a forma como você fez não é exatamente a mais adequada, programaticamente falando, pois você suprime um erro ao invés de lidar com ele.

Também, você assume um *case* específico para comparação o que não é certo haja vista existirem diversos *frameworks* JS que, assumindo que eles enviem esse cabeçalho automaticamente, podem, de repente, capitalizar algumas letras de forma diferente, por exemplo.

Dito isso:

```
function isXmlHttpRequest() {

    $header = ( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', $_SERVER ) ?
              $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : '' );

    return ( strcmp( $header, 'xmlhttprequest' ) == 0 );
}

if( ! isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

   // Acesso negado
}
```

- **Restringir origem XHR**

Ultimamente aqui no SOpt muito tem se falado sobre o controle das origens de uma XHR. AJAX não é crossdomain, mas pode passar a ser por causa de um servidor mal-configurado. Melhor prevenir do que remediar:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain.com");
```

- **Tokens**

A forma mais recomendada é anexar à URL da requisição algum valor aleatório o qual você, e somente você tenha como validar.

Isso pode ser desde um hash MD5 de um [uniqid()](http://www.php.net/uniqid) armazenado em sessão, apesar do que se estiverem MESMO interessado em violar sua aplicação sessions podem ser capturadas. Não entro em detalhes por não saber exatamente como isso é feito.

Ou então *token* "de verdade", que pode até mesmo vir do mesmo [uniqid()](http://www.php.net/uniqid) mas criptografado com um algorítimo parrudo (coisas do RIJNDAEL 256 bits ou mais), armazenado num banco de dados associado ao ID do usuário, de curta duração, sendo regenerado constantemente.

- **SSL**

SSL deveria vir em primeiro lugar, mas seja por disponibilidade aquisitiva ou complexidade de implantação, deixei-a por último. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> comece a executar a URL sem parar , tornando o site vulnerável

Seu site ou é vulnerável ou ainda não se descrobriu alguma vulnerabilidade, e mais acessos não criam vulnerabilidades.

Ataques DDoS não podem ser evitados, somente mitigados por técnicas de controle de acesso que tem nada a ver com sua aplicação. É quem lida com seus servidores que deve se preocupar com isso.

Vulnerabilidades a XSS também não são criadas por muitos acessos, mas por falta de limpeza de dados inseridos no banco e impressos de volta na tela.

É provavel que você tenha tentado usar um token de inserção de post mas de uma vez, e o sistema do G+ recusou, um exemplo disso em uma aplicação é:

**formulario.html:**

```
<input type="text" name="mensagem" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token_de_um_so_acesso ?>" />
<button type="submit" value="enviar"/>
```

**formulario.php:**

```
<?php
    $post = [...]
    if(checar_se_token_foi_usado($post['token']))
        exit('adios');
```

Comment: Imagina uma aplicação em que depende dos comentários dos utilizadores, como o foursquare. Ao inserir comentários via AJAX e não bloquear a execução directa da URL, estou permitindo que qualquer mal intencionado atrapalhe o conceito da aplicação. Mesmo que o IP fique bloqueado, há sempre maneira de contornar isso. Pode não ser um vulnerabilidade DDoS/XSS ( tens toda razão ) mas é uma vulnerabilidade.

Comment: Mas veja, se a minha requisição é via AJAX, terei que trocar o token toda vez que um post é inserido, ou retorno o novo token na resposta da aquisição ajax ou utilizo ajax para obter outro token, o que iria dar na mesma porque teria que bloquear essa chamada também. Se retornar o novo token na resposta da requisição, bastava ter um pouco de conhecimento para obter o novo token e utiliza-lo em um script malicioso.

Comment: Usando um token random de 64 bits, o "pouco de conhecimento" necessário para acertar seria o equivalente a milênios de computadores potentes tentando acertar.

Comment: Como o Bruno confirmou abaixo, tokens é a maneira mais recomendade, inclusivo sistemas de ecommerce os usam, o resto é só firula que qualquer hacker entendido vai rir as suas custas.